# Python- Exporting a Dataframe into a csv

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, tabula-py

I'm trying to write a dataframe file to a csv using pandas. I'm getting the following error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'. I believe I'm writing the syntax correctly, but could anyone point out where my syntax is incorrect in trying to write a dataframe to a csv?
This is link the link of the file: https://s22.q4cdn.com/351912490/files/doc_financials/quarter_spanish/2018/2018.02.25_Release-4Q18_ingl%C3%A9s.pdf
Thanks for your time!

```
import tabula 
from tabula import read_pdf
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_json, read_csv


a = read_pdf(r"C:\Users\Emege\Desktop\micro 1 true\earnings_release.pdf",\
            multiple_tables= True, pages = 15, output_format = "csv",\
            )
print(a)

a.to_csv("a.csv",header = False, index = False,  encoding = "utf-8")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytlrY.jpg)

Comment: What's the output of A? Does it look like a dataframe? My assumption would be to simply pass it into a data frame with `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: The content of this page are three tables in pdf format, so i want to pass those tables into a csv format and then order that with pd.read_csv(). but the problem is that i get lists, not dataframes. So the problem is how to arrive to the dataframe

Comment: @damiansilva, could you post some contents of `a` directly into your question, instead of requiring visitors to download the PDF and run your code? As @Datanovice suggested, the first thing to try is to pass `a` to the DataFrame constructor and see what happens: `df = pd.DataFrame(a); df.to_csv('a.csv')`

Comment: Sorry guys, i´m new here. I put the content of that page in a image. I tried what Datanovice says, but it doesn´t work becuase of i´m lossing values.

Comment: no worries Damian, just had a quick look (had to install tabula-py and java [and add java to path!!]) and it seems you get nested lists with different sized table columns. You'll need to do some manual clean-up before passing this into Pandas try passing `pd.DataFrame(a[0])` which are your headers.

Comment: Ok, i will try that way.

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler do you recommend cropping the pdf and work with the tables individually?